# Open existing Form

Tags: c#, winforms, openform, newforms

I have this code:

```
  private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked_1(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
  {
      Form8 of = new Form8();
      of.ShowDialog();
  }
```

That button opens my form8 (good).
But if I click twice, the form duplicates, so I got 2 same form8.

Does any body knows how to just select (bring to front) the form8 if it is already open, when I click the linklabel for second time.
Thanks!

Comment: ShowDialog() is *modal*, it disables all the other window in the app.  So you are not supposed to be able to click "linkLabel1".  Pretty unclear what you did.

Comment: You can always disable and re-enable the link label before and after the dialog is shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainForm
{
    // Keep a reference to your popup form here, so you never create more than one instance
    private Form8 of = new Form8();

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked_1(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (of != null && of.IsDisposed)
            of = new Form8();

        // Call Show(), not ShowDialog() because ShowDialog will block the UI thread
        // until you close the dialog.
        of.Show();
        of.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `Form8`(`of` instance) is closed? It will throw `ObjectDisposedException`.

Comment: Changed to check for disposed form

Comment: That != null condition is redundant, It will never be true as we're not setting null anywhere. Yep I know it doesn't matter, so +1 ed

Comment: It's called defensive programming.  What if another developer decided to set of = null in another method?